# Adicionar Item no Spinner

Tags: java, android

Preciso usar Spinner no meu app...

Estou tendo dificuldade em adicionar elementos a lista.

Achei muito complicado.

Link: https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/

Teria outra forma de simplificar isso?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basicamente existem duas formas de adicionar item ao `Spinner`, fornecendo uma lista com uma matriz de strings definida em um [arquivo de recursos de string (*string resource*)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html?hl=pt-br) e programaticamente:

### **XML**

Para inserir a lista no `Spinner`, basta você criar um `string-array` no seu arquivo `strings.xml`. Veja:

**strings.xml**

```xml
<string name="linguagem_prompt">Escolha uma linguagem</string>
<string-array name="linguagens">
    <item>Java</item>
    <item>Python</item>
    <item>PHP</item>
    <item>Ruby</item>
</string-array>
```

Sucessivamente, `activity_main.xml` e defina android:entries com o nome criado em `strings.xml`.

**activity_main.xml**

```xml
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/linguagens"
    android:prompt="@string/linguagem_prompt" />
```

### **Programaticamente**

**MainActivity.class**

```java
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
List<String> linguagens = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Java","Python","PHP","Ruby"));

ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, linguagens );
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

**activity_main.xml**

```xml
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/linguagem_prompt" />
```

Para mais detalhes sobre `Spinner`, veja [na documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html?hl=pt-br).

Comment: Excepcional. Muito obrigado !

Answer (score 6):

Você pode declarar um array de String e incluir nele

Exemplo:

```
String spinnerArray[] = {"Item1", "Item2"};
```

E ai incluir no adapter padrão:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
seu_spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```